# No consumers, yet when I publish something an ack is immediately returned why? (golang/rabbitmq)

Tags: go, rabbitmq, message-queue

Below is the publisher code that I use. It requires acks before the message is taken off the queue. It's suppose to print out that it receives an Ack or nack (at the bottom of the code) from a consumer. If you just run the publisher code below by itself (without running a consumer code at same time), it suppose to just hang, waiting for ack or nack but it doesn't, it prints out an ack as if a consumer had sent it. So I'm confused if I have any part of the code wrong.

For the base code I used code from rabbitmq's official tutorial: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-go.html

For ack/nack part of the code I followed this: https://agocs.org/blog/2014/08/19/rabbitmq-best-practices-in-go/

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {

    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

     ch.Confirm(false)

    ack, nack := ch.NotifyConfirm(make(chan uint64, 1), make(chan uint64, 1))

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "hello", // name
        false,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    body := "hello"
    err = ch.Publish(
        "",     // exchange
        q.Name, // routing key
        true,  // mandatory
        false,  // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{
            ContentType: "text/plain",
            Body:        []byte(body),
        })
    log.Printf(" [x] Sent %s", body)
    failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

    select {
      case tag := <-ack:
          log.Println("Acked ", tag)
      case tag := <-nack:
          log.Println("Nack alert! ", tag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing publisher confirm acks and nacks with consumer side acks and nacks.

The documentation states:

> For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the
>   exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty
>   list of queues). If the message is also published as mandatory, the
>   basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack. The same is true
>   for negative acknowledgements (basic.nack).
>
> For routable messages, the basic.ack is sent when a message has been
>   accepted by all the queues. For persistent messages routed to durable
>   queues, this means persisting to disk. For mirrored queues, this means
>   that all mirrors have accepted the message.

So you are seeing the correct behaviour. RabbitMQ is confirming that the messages arrived at the queue.

Comment: Because if Rabbit waited to ack a pub until the message was consumed and acked, it would defeat the entire purpose of a message queue altogether.